# Homebrew cannot link libpng trying to install gdal

Tags: homebrew, gdal, topojson

I'm trying to install gdal via homebrew so I can start working with topojson, but I keep getting this error and I'm not sure how to resolve it?

```
k-6177:Cellar k$ brew install gdal
==> Installing dependencies for gdal: libpng, giflib, libtiff, lzlib, proj, libgeotiff, geos, sqlite, freexl, libxml2, json-c, liblwgeom, libspatialite
Error: Cannot link libpng
Another version is already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.16
```

Comment: Have you tried `brew remove libpng` then `brew install gdal`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Looks like I just needed to change some permissions. I used the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
```

Comment: Should I undo this after the installation is complete? It seems a bit dangerous to change the ownership of /user/local like this.

Answer (score 5):

I did `brew unlink libpng` (or any other "already linked" package).